# Values displayed after realloc are weird

Tags: c, malloc

I called `malloc` and then I want to cut size in half using `realloc` when i  display values of relocated `malloc` few numbers shows as 0, is that normal or I messed something up?

```
double main()
{
    double *test;
    int size = 10;
    int sizes;
    int i = 0;
    double value;
    test = (double*)malloc(size*sizeof(double));
    if(test == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nInsert values : \n");
        for(i=0;i<=size;)
        {
            scanf("%lf",&*(test+i));
            if(*(test+i)==0.0)
            {
                break;
            }
            if(i>=size)
            {
                size=size+2;
                test = realloc(test, size*sizeof(double));
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    sizes=size/2;
    test = realloc(test, sizes*sizeof(double));
    printf("\nSaved values : \n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("%lf\n",*(test+i));
    }

}
```

I want to learn some coding so please tell me if and what I am doing wrong.

Comment: No need to cast `malloc()` in C, for the same reason `realloc()` does not need to be casted.

Comment: This `i<=size` looks fishy.

Comment: I recommend that you stop using pointer arithmetic syntax for your "arrays", and instead use e.g. `test[i]` (instead of `*(test + i)`). It will make the code easier to read (and is less to write).

Comment: You finally reallocate `test` down to `sizes=size/2;` but then loop over `i=0;i<size;` Do you do this by intention?

Comment: That first `realloc` in the loop reading input makes no sense to me. You *know* that there will be `size + 1` elements, why not allocate it from the start? Why have dynamic allocation at all instead of plain arrays?

Comment: This `&*(test+i)` is the same as `test+i`.

Comment: `double main()` Hu?! `main()` ought to return `int`.

Comment: @alk i use realloc in loop, because wanted to alocate malloc for some random size (in this case 10) and then increase it when place runs out.

Comment: You are aware that `sizes` and `size` are not the same, aren't you?

Comment: And my 1st comment did not refer to the `realloc()`  in the loop, but to the final one, after the reallocating loop.

Comment: you allocate space for `size` (10) elements, but then loop `for i = 0; i <= size; i++`. Check how many elements that is.
When you run out of space, you first use the `size + 1`th element (effectively write outside allocated memory bounds) and then do a `reallocate()` - this should be the other way round.

Comment: @alk I know that `sizes` and `size` aren't same so when i use size in `for(i=0;i<size;i++)` i display table before cutting and there are some leftovers after cutting and i want to know if those leftovers are normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I well understand you stop to read value at EOF or when the read value is 0, and 0 is not memorized, and when the read is done you want to reduce the allocates vector to the minimal size, in that case :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int size = 10;
    double *test = malloc(size*sizeof(double));

    if(test == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
      int i = 0;
      double value;

      printf("\nInsert values : \n");
      while ((scanf("%lf",&value) == 1) && (value != 0))
      {
          if (i >= size) /* == is enough */
          {
            size += 2; /* I add 2 entries as you */
            test = realloc(test, size*sizeof(double));
          }
          test[i++] = value;
      }

      /* remove possible extra entry at the end */
      if (i != size)
          test = realloc(test, i*sizeof(double));

      size = i;

      printf("\nSaved values : \n");
      for(i=0 ;i<size; ++i)
      {
        printf("%lf\n",test[i]);
      }

      free(test);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here:

1. This

   ```
   for(i=0;i<=size;)
   ```

   makes this

   ```
     scanf("%lf",&*(test+i));
   ```

   scan into memory *one element beyond the allocated memory* on the last iteration before reallocating. Doing so **invokes undefined behaviour**. Already from now on anything may happen.
2. Those two lines

   ```
   sizes=size/2;
   test = realloc(test, sizes*sizeof(double));
   ```

   shrink the valid memory to the half of its size, and then this loop

   ```
   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
   {
     printf("%lf\n",*(test+i));
   }
   ```

   tries to read out the second half's value which just had been shrinked away. This half's memory is *not valid any more*. Trying to read it **invokes undefined behaviour** as well.

So to answer your question:

> or i messed something up

Yes you did, namely by invoking undefined behaviour. Do not do that.

Comment: so i have to change `sizes` to `size` and everything should be kinda ok ?

Comment: @przemo10371: You have to fix *both* issues. Undefined behaviour has to be avoided in *any* case.